# Property 'map' is used before its initialization. (Google Maps in Angular)

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3

I am working on implementing `google maps` in an angular webpage but I am getting this error (The app still works)

Edit:
Just to clarify, The map works, the markers also work, I'm just getting the error in my Visual studio code and a method not implemented in my inspection of the webpage(which is an exception by the map not being initialized)

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:29:15 - error TS2729: Property 'map' is used before its initialization.
> 29     map: this.map,
> ~~~
> src/app/app.component.ts:15:3
> 15   map: google.maps.Map;
> ~~~
> 'map' is declared here.
> src/app/app.component.ts:36:15 - error TS2729: Property 'map' is used before its initialization.
> 36     map: this.map,
> ~~~
> src/app/app.component.ts:15:3
> 15   map: google.maps.Map;
> ~~~
> 'map' is declared here.

my app **component.ts**

```typescript
    import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
        
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    
    })
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
      title = 'maps-v1';
      @ViewChild('mapContainer', {static: false}) gmap: ElementRef;
      map: google.maps.Map;
      lat = 37.37;
      lng = -122.04;
      coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng);
    
    
      mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
        center: this.coordinates,
        zoom: 12,
        gestureHandling:"cooperative",
      };
    
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.coordinates,
        map: this.map,
        title:"Start"
      });
    
      mark2=new google.maps.Marker({
        label: "TEST",
        position:{lat:37.37,lng:-122.03},
        map: this.map,
        title:"TESTERSZ"
    
      });
    
      ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.mapInitializer();
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
        
      }
      
    
      mapInitializer() {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, 
        this.mapOptions);
        this.marker.setMap(this.map);
        this.mark2.setMap(this.map);
    
       }
       
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error was because the markers object is initialized first before the map is getting initialized in `afterViewInit`

The solution is to move markers initializations into `mapInitializer()` and put them after `this.map = new google.maps` statement.

```
mapInitializer() {
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: this.coordinates,
    map: this.map, // this.map will contain the map object here
    title:"Start"
  });

  const mark2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    label: "TEST",
    position:{lat:37.37,lng:-122.03},
    map: this.map,
    title:"TESTERSZ"
  });

  marker.setMap(this.map);
  mark2.setMap(this.map);
}
```

Comment: This solution kinda worked, after I switched the marker's location to be inside the map initializer i than had to add a "marker; any;" inside the app component.

Answer (score 0):

you must wait for the map to initialize so change it like the following

```
 mapInitializer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
    }, 500);
    this.marker.setMap(this.map);
    this.mark2.setMap(this.map);

 }
```